# Is It possible to move or transfer an encrypted iPhone backup between computers?

Tags: iphone, backup, encryption

I have a new MacBook Pro and backed up (encrypted) my iPhone on the machine. I would like to transfer that backup to my iMac desktop and open it in iTunes on that machine. Is it possible to transfer the encrypted backup on the MacBook to the iMac? Thx.

Comment: Have you tried just finding the file and dragging it? I'm not sure if it would work but you could try it and see if the backup can be recognized and decrypting on the iMac

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Alternatively you could create another encrypted back up your iPhone to the iMac by just creating a second backup.

Comment: Thx. The phone was restored to factory settings after the backup...that is why I need to move the backup to iMac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely! The iPhone backups are stored in your user account's app data section.

1. Open Finder, and select the “Go” menu at the top of the screen. Hold the Option key, and select the “Library” menu option from the Go menu. (On OSX Lion and above, Library will only appear with the Option key held.)
2. From Library, navigate to Application Support -> MobileSync -> Backup.

(In iTunes preferences -> Devices, you can also right-click on the backup and select Show in Finder on Mac.)

In here, your backups are folders named with the device id for the iPhone (and a date after it sometimes). Make sure you grab the whole folder, and put the folder in on the new computer in the Backup folder there. You can make the folders if iTunes hasn't yet.

Here's a blog post I wrote about it on Mac and Windows, and matching up the UDID to your iPhone.
https://deciphertools.com/blog/where-are-iphone-backups/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Possible to find iPhone encrypted backup password in Keychain files on MacBook...for forgotten password?

Comment: Yes :) I have a walkthrough for looking up a saved backup password in Keychain Manager on the second half of this page: https://deciphertools.com/support/knowledge-base/decipher-textmessage-is-asking-me-for-a-password-for-my-iphone-backup/